# Select distinct items with their corresponding last row in mysql

Tags: mysql

i created a table in mysql.

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int,item int, dt DATE, qty INT); 
INSERT INTO t VALUES 
(1,1,'2007-1-1',5),(2,1,'2007-1-2',6), (3,1,'2007-1-3',7),(4,1,'2007-1-4',8), 
(5,1,'2007-1-5',9),(6,1,'2007-1-6',10),(7,1,'2007-1-7',11),(8,1,'2007-1-8',12),
(9,1,'2007-1-9',13), (10,2,'2007-1-1',6), (11,2,'2007-1-2',7),(12,2,'2007-1-3',8), 
(13,2,'2007-1-4',9), (14,2,'2007-1-5',10), (15,2,'2007-1-6',11),(16,2,'2007-1-7',12), 
(17,2,'2007-1-8',13), (18,2,'2007-1-9',14);
```

[image]

i wanted to find `exponential moving average` for each item.

so i found a code for that.

```
select item,dt,qty,
  @a := ( @a*.3 + qty*.7)  AS moving_avg
from t
Join (select @a := 0) as X
group by item,moving_avg,qty,dt
order by item,qty,dt
```

and i got result.

[image]

but i want to select only the last entry of row for each item, which i have highlighted in my image.

i'e my final table should only contain

```
item    dt                     qty     moving_avg
 1     09-Jan-07 12:00:00 AM    13    12.571358275
 2     09-Jan-07 12:00:00 AM    14    13.5715860340449
```

ie. distinct item with their corresponding last row.
Any ideas how do i do it?
maybe by tweaking my code for moving average itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend your code by retrieving the max `dt` per item in a subquery a joining this on your result, which also needs to be pushed into a subquery:

```
select t1.*
    from
        (select item,dt,qty,
          @a := ( @a*.3 + qty*.7)  AS moving_avg
         from t
         Join (select @a := 0) as X
         group by item,moving_avg,qty,dt
         order by item,qty,dt) t1
    inner join
        (select item, max(dt) as maxdt
         from t
         group by item) t2 on t1.item=t2.item and t1.dt=t2.maxdt
```

Caveat: if you have 2 records with the exactly the same `dt` value per item, then the query will return both of them.

Comment: sir,it can't have since the value would change with respect to date, since it is a moving average

Comment: the code is not working when i have multiple items with different quantity on same date. 
i tried to do sum(qty) in your code but it was giving me multiples of 7 as moving avg. Is there any way to resolve it?
my [sql fiddle demo for better understanding](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25ea42/4)

Comment: one thing that i thought was to create an intermediate table t2 which will do sum(product_views) and then use t2 for moving avg..

Any better ideas ? without creating an intermediate table.